# How to set width/height of iOS UIAlertController

Tags: c#, ios, uialertcontroller

I've been trying to figure out how to change the height and width of the `UIAlertController`for a couple of weeks now.  You apparently can do it as I've seen several Swift examples, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019701/how-to-change-uialertcontroller-height).  I have no experience with Swift and my numerous attempts at converting the code to C# have been extremely frustrating.

My problem in a nutshell is this.  I'm using `ZXing` to scan barcodes and I use the `UIAlertController` to display success/failure messages that popup over everything displayed on the screen.  The only thing that I can get to do that is `UIAlertController`.  I've tried using my own popup view based on `UIView` and using the `RG.Plugins.Popup` `NUGet` package as well as number of other `NUGet` packages based on the `RG.Plugins.Popup` package, nothing works and so I am left with `UIAlertController`.  My code is:

```
        // This code is how I get the popup to show over everything
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;

        // I add a label to display personalized messages
        UILabel label = new UILabel(frame: new CGRect(0, 75, 270, 150));
        label.Lines = 5;

        var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(message, messagetype, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

        // My attempts at changing the size
        //okAlertController.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new CGSize(600, 1000); 
        //View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Frame = new CGRect(0,0,500,1000);
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }
        if (showLabel )
        {

            label.Text = labelText;
            label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(label.Font.PointSize);
            okAlertController.View.AddSubview(label);
        }

        // I change the background color based on success or error
        if (messagetype.ToUpper() == "ERROR")
        {
            okAlertController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        }
        else if (messagetype.ToUpper() == "SUCCESS")
        {
            okAlertController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        }
        // Show the popup
        vc.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to figure it out.  I added a `NSLayoutConstraint` to the `UIAlertController`.  My code is now:

```
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        UILabel label = new UILabel(frame: new CGRect(0, 75, 270, 150));
        label.Lines = 5;


        var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(message, messagetype, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        var height = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(okAlertController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1.0f, (nfloat)(vc.View.Frame.Height * 0.50));
        okAlertController.View.AddConstraint(height);
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }
        if (showLabel )
        {

            label.Text = labelText;
            label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(label.Font.PointSize);
            okAlertController.View.AddSubview(label);
        }
        if (messagetype.ToUpper() == "ERROR")
        {
            okAlertController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        }
        else if (messagetype.ToUpper() == "SUCCESS")
        {
            okAlertController.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        }
        vc.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
```

I now get the height I need.